# aufofs fail to mount cifs shares on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, cifs, autofs

I followed the instructions to mount my cifs shares via autofs (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Autofs/) but unfortunately, autofs doesn't any of them.

/etc/auto.master looks as following

```
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is a 'master' automounter map and it has the following format:
# mount-point [map-type[,format]:]map [options]
# For details of the format look at auto.master(5).
#
#/misc  /etc/auto.misc
/media/cifs /etc/auto.cifs-shares --timeout=60 --ghost
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#       "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#       options are explicitly given.
#
#/net   -hosts
#
# Include /etc/auto.master.d/*.autofs
# To add an extra map using this mechanism you will need to add
# two configuration items - one /etc/auto.master.d/extra.autofs file
# (using the same line format as the auto.master file)
# and a separate mount map (e.g. /etc/auto.extra or an auto.extra NIS map)
# that is referred to by the extra.autofs file.
#
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
#
# If you have fedfs set up and the related binaries, either
# built as part of autofs or installed from another package,
# uncomment this line to use the fedfs program map to access
# your fedfs mounts.
#/nfs4  /usr/sbin/fedfs-map-nfs4 nobind
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master
```

and accordingly /etc/auto.cifs-share

```
documents -fstype=cifs,uid=${UID},credentials=/home/${USER}/.smbcredentials ://nas.local/documents
multimedia -fstype=cifs,uid=${UID},credentials=/home/${USER}/.smbcredentials ://nas.local/multimedia
software -fstype=cifs,uid=${UID},credentials=/home/${USER}/.smbcredentials ://nas.local/software
```

Unfortunately, /media/cifs stays empty.
I did a plausibility check if the credentials are working by running

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/${USER}/.smbcredentials,uid=${UID} //nas.local/multimedia  /mnt
```

So everything is fine there, so I guess it isn't the problem with the cifs authentication on the servers side.

Hence I stop the service and ran it in foreground giving me the output below.

````
$ sudo automount -f -v```
Starting automounter version 5.1.8, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.05
mounted indirect on /media/cifs with timeout 60, freq 15 seconds
ghosting enabled
attempting to mount entry /media/cifs/autorun.inf
attempting to mount entry /media/cifs/.xdg-volume-info
lookup(program): lookup for autorun.inf failed
failed to mount /media/cifs/autorun.inf
lookup(program): lookup for .xdg-volume-info failed
failed to mount /media/cifs/.xdg-volume-info
````

Well, I found a tracked bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1855318 dealing with Ubuntu 20.4. At that point I do not really know how to solve this since if it's really a bug I wonder that 4 years later this is still an issue, especially as autofs is a pretty heavily used package. Thus, my suspicion is growing that I have a flaw in my configuration. Hence any help is highly appreciated.

6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Gnome: 42.9

Comment: Is the behavior different if you change the mount point from `/media/cifs` to somewhere like `/mnt/cifs`?

Comment: Changing to /mnt/cifs doesn't work either although the output for running it in foreground changes to
`sudo automount -f -v
Starting automounter version 5.1.8, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.05
mounted indirect on /mnt/cifs with timeout 60, freq 15 seconds
ghosting enabled`